# Liferay 6.2 PortletURL.setParameter() prepends underscores to parameter names

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, jsr286

I am working on a project using Liferay 6.2 on JBoss ES 6.2.  I need to be able to create a action URL inside an action method.  The action method is looking up some data, building a JSONArray, and then setting an attribute equal to the resulting JSON string.  Part of that JSON data needs an action url to another action within the same portlet.

The problem I am running into is that the generated URL seems to force any parameters I set include two underscores to the parameter name.

For instance:

```
PortletURL actionUrl = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(actionRequest, portletId, plid, PortletRequest.ACTION_PHASE);
actionUrl.setPortletMode(LiferayPortletMode.VIEW);
actionUrl.setWindowState(WindowState.NORMAL);
actionUrl.setParameter("guid", guid);
actionUrl.setParameter("javax.portlet.action", "myAction");
```

Ends up generating something like:

```
http://localhost:8000/group/mySite/myPortlet?p_auth=fsdweD2&p_p_id=p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&__guid=1234567890&__javax.portlet.action=myAction
```

Notice the `__guid` and `__javax.portlet.action`.  As a result, the portlet ends up running the `doView()` instead of `myAction()`.

I have also tried to create a friendly url to solve the issue, but then I run into the issue of how to generate the friendly url with the proper site context AND the required `p_auth` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL generated doesn't have portlet ID set properly as I see p_p_id is empty in URL. Please check if you are passing correct portlet ID.